# SQL Server Service Broker POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING(STATUS = ON)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

We are hosting one of our solutions which was originally built on SQL Server 2008 R2 and this instance is hosted on a SQL Server 2008 instance (not R2). The database created fine but for some reason the service broker queues were created with:

```
POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING(STATUS = OFF)
```

I have tried setting this to on but with no luck, we have always declared the queue like this:

```
CREATE QUEUE QueueName WITH STATUS=ON, ACTIVATION 
(STATUS = ON, MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, 
PROCEDURE_NAME = QueueProcedureName,   EXECUTE AS OWNER);
```

Is there a way to create the queue as about with the defaults of R2?

EDIT - More Info:

This is the error message which makes no sense as works fine on 2008 R2.
GO
ALTER QUEUE [Store].[UpdateStoredPublishingSegmentUsersSendQueue]
    WITH POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING(STATUS = ON);

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING'.

Comment: `I have tried setting this to on but with no luck` define 'no luck'. Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the version of sql server. The POISON-MESSAGE_HANDLING is not supported in version less than 2008 R2. Hope this helps!

Comment: I removed that part and the queue was created. 
CREATE QUEUE [Core].[TestSendQueue] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF   ON [PRIMARY] 
I think the issue is more complex because it is not supported in Sql 2008.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: I haven't tried the following commands, as I am running on 2005 which doesn't support the POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING option.

Have you tried the [ALTER QUEUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189529.aspx) command after executing the CREATE?

```
ALTER QUEUE <queue name> WITH 
    POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING ( STATUS = ON )
```

In alternative try modifying your CREATE command like this:

```
CREATE QUEUE <queue name> WITH 
    STATUS=ON, 
    ACTIVATION (
        STATUS = ON, 
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, 
        PROCEDURE_NAME = <activated sproc name>,
        EXECUTE AS OWNER
    ),
    POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING ( STATUS = ON );
```